# Is the vendor directory required for HTML5?

Tags: html, vendor

Is it necessary to use vendor when you write code in HTML5 (ex. css/vendor/bootstrap.min.css and js/vendor/bootstrap.min.js)?

Comment: If you're talking about file structure, then just stick to what you're comfortable with.

Comment: Ah, the mythical "somewhere" that puts a lot of crazy ideas into people's heads. Do you have a link to the somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

No. The `vendor` directory is a convention used by some projects (HTML5 Boilerplate, AngularJS…). If you don't use such tools, you can put your code where you want. If you use such tools, you generally should *not* put code in this directory, because it has a special meaning.

Comment: yes, I use html 5 boilerplate and bootstrap framework.